# jquery - fancybox inline unique id

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, unique, inline

**Hola!**

I have php loading and XML file. Then once the XML file is loaded, it displays images from the XML on a page.

I'm using the foreach function (obviously). Each image that is loaded will have a button underneath called "Edit".

My problem is [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).  When someone hits the "Edit" button underneath the image, I  need [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) Inline to be UNIQUE.  Right now it's just loading the first ID it sees for all.

**Overall:**
I need [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) Inline to have an UNIQUE ID for the loop.

I hope I've made sense explaining this.

**Here is my code**

```
<? 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myPhotos.xml');


if( isset($xml->image) ) 
    {

        foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
            {   

                echo '  
                    <div class="col-xs-4">

                    <span class="img">
                    <img src="' . $child['src'] . '" alt="gallery image" />
                    </span>

                    <div style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:210px;">
                    <span style=""><a class="btn btn-info editText" href="#Inline">Edit</a></span>
                    </div>

                    </div>





                     <div id="Inline" style="display:none;width:500px;">
                        <p>
                        <img src="' . $child['src'] . '" alt="gallery image" />
                        </p>
                    </div>  '; 

            }

         }


        else {

       }


?>
```

Thanks!

I hope someone can help me out. I just can't seem to get it working. 
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JFK  Thanks, I got it working right after I posted this question (of course) haha

**I'm using this before my loop**:

```
$i = 1;
```

**Then right before my loop ends, I'm using**:

```
$i ++;
```

**Then I assign my id's like this:**

```
id="'.$i.'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $key => $child)
```

then

```
<div id="Inline$key" style="display:none;width:500px;">
```

or

```
<div id="Inline'.$key.'" style="display:none;width:500px;">
```

and

```
<a class="btn btn-info editText" href="#Inline$key">Edit...
```

or

```
<a class="btn btn-info editText" href="#Inline'.$key.'">Edit...
```